# jQuery when using window resize if statement not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement, window-resize

I searched a lot about this problem, but couldn't find any answer that realy suits my needs. I want to place css opacity efect on same image when i hover some div on other part of my web page.

The code look something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

        opacityEffect();
 $(window).resize(function() {
  opacityEffect();
 });
     
 function opacityEffect() {
          
  var windowsize = $(window).width();
  if (windowsize > 980) {
   $('.hover-box a').on('mouseover', function(){
    $('.image-box img').animate({
     opacity: 0.2
    }, 0 );
                        });
   $('.hover-box a').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('.image-box img').animate({
     opacity: 1
    }, 0 );
   });
                 }
        }
});
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="image-box">
      <img src="images/image1" alt="" title="">
  </div>
  
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
                
  <div class="hover-box">
    <a href="">Hover mouse here</a>
  </div>
```

The problem is that it applies css opacity effect under 980px and over 980px, when resize page window. How can this be? I realy don't understand this. It looks like "if" doesn't exists.

Somehow I got it working by literally overriding it with same code in ELSE statement with first opacity value changed to 1, but this slowed opacity effect on image from 1 to 3 seconds after window resize. Any sugestions? Thanks

### ----------

First, I corected my code that I badly typed. And than I researched Tyson post

> EDIT: Your code is going to continuously add event handlers as the window resizes.

So I found this solution (struggling a bit to fully understand), but it works for my problem:

```js
jQuery(function($){

 // flag to allow hover
 var hoverAllowed = true;
   
 // hover function
 $('.hover-box a').on('mouseover', function(){
  if (hoverAllowed) {
   $('.image-box img').animate({
    opacity: 0.2
   }, 0 );
  }
 });  
     
 $('.hover-box a').on('mouseleave', function(){
  if (hoverAllowed) {
   $('.image-box img').animate({
    opacity: 1
   }, 0 );
  }
 });
    
 // check if browser size is compatible with hover event
 onResize = function() {
  //if browser size is smaller than 980, disallow hover
  if($(window).width() < 980){
   hoverAllowed = false;
  }
                // if browser size is greater than 980, allow hover
  else{
   hoverAllowed = true;
  }
  // checking is hover allowed or not
  //console.log(hoverAllowed);
 }
   
 $(document).ready(onResize);
 $(window).bind('resize', onResize);
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a Javascript error on the second last line:

```
        });
});
```

Should be

```
        };
});
```

EDIT: Your code is going to continuously add event handlers as the window resizes.